# "Not a valid date in accord with the XML format for ABAP" error while calling SAP PI web service

Tags: .net, wcf, abap, sap-pi, sap-xi

I'm getting this `System.ServiceModel.FaultException` calling an SAP XI/PI web service from my .NET application via WCF:

> CX_SY_CONVERSION_NO_DATE_TIME:XSLT exception. An error occurred when deserializing in the simple transformation program /1BCDWB/WSSB430AA018B4EA689BF0.Value 7/12/2010 is not a valid date in accord with the XML format for ABAP

The date in question is a string field that I'm formatting with the .NET `DateTime.ToShortDateString()` method.

Can anyone tell me what the valid "XML format for ABAP" is for dates?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try YYYY-MM-DD otherwise you could browse the services wsdl and see how the date type is defined.

Comment: Mind the spaces too, wasted hrs by leaving a space before the y => {0:yyyy-MM-dd}